Getting unauthenticated when i was able to generate token in laravel sactum
Hi guys I have this project laravel v.10 backend and vue CLI front end. I used laravel sactum for authentication.
Now my issue is, if I want to go into this route, I get  {"message":"Unauthenticated."} response. But I was able to login and secure a token in the front end.
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/scans', [ScanController::class, 'index']);

this is my laravel login code
public function login(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email|',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if(!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json(['message'=> 'Invalid login details'], 401);
        }

        $user = $request->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
        return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token'=>$token]);
    }

I can use this api route
Route::get('/scans', [ScanController::class,'index']);

but i wont be able to call this code $user = $request->user(); as its gonna show null.
hope someone points out what I am missing here.
thanks

Try  $user = auth()->user(); or $user = request()->user();

thanks for your feedback, however these doesn't  work either.

Probably $request->user() will not work at that time, so use Auth.
$user = Auth::user();


thanks for the feedback. I tried this as well but doesn't work.
